# Chapter formatting and spacing

Tags: chapters, titlesec, thesis, report, minionpro

I use report document class and the thing is that I would like to change the chapter both in format, letterspace and place on the page.

Right now a chapter look like this: 
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

I have tried following command without luck.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[letterspace=100]
\titleformat{\section}{\lsstyle\uppercase}{\section}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex}{0ex}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\end{document}
```

My last question is, how can change my "11pt" to "11.5pt"? Is there a way of doing this.

I would appreciate all kind of help.

Thank you!

New picture:
[image]

UPDATED preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 

% Different usepackages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro} %% MinionPro
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{tabu}

% Chapter
\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{100}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{ \figureversion{lining}}{\lsstyle\Large\MakeUppercase\chaptername\enspace \huge\thechapter}{2ex}{\huge\bfseries}%\uppercase
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{\lsstyle\LARGE\MakeUppercase}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2.5ex}{12ex}

% item / enumerate

\usepackage{enumitem}

% HTML code

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}


% Figure

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

% More pdf-pages at same site

\usepackage{pdfpages}

% References
\usepackage[round, colon, sort, authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\def\citeapos#1{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}

% Quotes

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

% Page margins
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}


% PDF background 
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% Random text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}% <- !
% Defining MyStyle
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\small{\leftmark} \ \ \hspace{2pt} {\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt} \ \small{\thepage}}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\small{\thepage} \ \ \hspace{2pt} {\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt} \ \lsstyle\small{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}\ \thechapter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\lsstyle\uppercase{##1}}{}}
}
% Redefining the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} %Clean headers
\fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
\fancyfoot[RO]{{\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt} \ \thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage \ \hspace{2pt} {\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
}
```

UPDATED picture

[image]

UPDATED - TOC
[image]

Comment: Concerning the fontsize: A KOMA-class can do this easily. The other stuff you are asking for can also be done with almost no effort, though an up to date KOMA is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that? I corrected your code, which couldn't compile (cf. `\usepackage[letterspace=100]`, which loads absolutely nothing). Also, if you want to change the formatting of chapters, use `titleformat{\chapter}``…

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{microtype}
 \SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{100}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{ \figureversion{lining}}{\lsstyle\Large\MakeUppercase\chaptername\enspace \huge\thechapter}{2ex}{\LARGE\bfseries#1}%\uppercase
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{\lsstyle\LARGE}{}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2.5ex}{12ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

It’s finished, finally. But it takes some time

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A first chapter}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\setcounter{chapter}{7}

\chapter{Conclusions}

A peremptory conclusion. A peremptory conclusion. A peremptory conclusion. A peremptory conclusion. A peremptory conclusion. A peremptory conclusion. A peremptory conclusion. A peremptory conclusion.

\end{document}
```

As for the `11.5pt` size, I'm not sure the difference will be noticeable. I suppose that, if you compile with `XeLaTeX`, it can be done with `fontspec` and the opentype version of Minion Pro. Not tested, though.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear Bernard. Thank you so much. It raises just one new problem. I have uploaded a photo of a Conclusion chapter. When I put your code in - it makes me some trouble with all the rest of my chapters. I want the chapters to look like the uploaded picture, if possible.

Comment: In addition: I want the same format for "ACNOWLEDGEMENT" in my "References", "Table of Contents", "List of figures", "List of tables", "Abstract" and "Chapters" as well, if possible. And second, how do I manage the position of these on a page? (they should be on the same spot)

Comment: I'll look at that a little later. In your initial post, there were very few information. Now it will be easier.

Comment: @A. F. I've updated my answer, with a different formatting for numbered and unnumbered chapters (such as table of contents, references, &c.). You can fine-tune formatting details and spacing from this basis.

Comment: Hmm @Bernard. I have updated my preamble and included your code, but it won't work. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It puts "POP" in front of the head-style?

Comment: Chapter "1" is much bigger than "chapter".

Comment: `Much` bigger, I don't know… I made it purposely: on the image you posted, the chapter number looks significantly bigger than ‘CHAPTER’, so I deccided to set the size to `\huge` vs `\Large`. I changed the code to `\LARGE`. See if it's more like you want. Intermediate sizes  can be specified too.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. Can you maybe see what's wrong with my new updated preamble? When I run your new code it won't work.

Comment: I have updated my post with a new picture of "ACKNOWLEDGEMENT" it is now "`POPACKNOWLEDGEMENT"

Comment: There seems to be a conflict with `color`.  The solution consists in using the `explicit` option of `titlesec`, see my modified code. Ther is also a problem with `tocloft` which redoes the formatting of the table  of contents name. Do you really need it? In case you really want to change the formatting of the table of contents, `titlesec` has the subpackage `titletoc` which most probably won't interfere.

Comment: Btw, don't load `fixltx2e` if your formats are recent: it's all incorporated in the kernel since the beginning of this year. Also use `xcolor` rather than `color`, and  don't use the `pdftex` option for `graphicx`.

Comment: Bernard, you are my hero! Thank you so much! Last question, do you know how to make the TOC (see last picture) without tocloft?

Comment: I've made this post as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250917/toc-chapter-above-chaptername?noredirect=1#comment597876_250917